# How do I find the number of common numbers occurring in 2nd array?

Tags: javascript

`commonCount(ar1, ar2)`

if `arr1 = [1,1,2,3,3]` and `arr2 = [1,4,3,1,1]`, the answer is 3

**My thought process:**

- initialize accumulator
- iterate through arr1
- if arr1[i] is in the arr2, add 1 to the accumulator
- remove the arr1[i] from arr2 (because don't want to have duplicate if the number already exist)
- return accumulator

*1) How do I check if arr1[i] is in the arr2?*

*2) How do I remove arr1[i] from arr2?*

Comment: *How do I check if arr1[i] is in the arr2?* `array.indexOf(arr[i])> -1`. *How do I remove arr1[i] from arr2?* `array.slice(index, numberOfElementsToRemove)`. But it will be tricky to tie both together.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go.

Comment: @Rajesh Shouldn't method be `splice` instead of `slice`?

Comment: @HassanImam Correct. It should be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
console.log([1,2,3,4,5].filter((n) => [1,1,2,10,11].includes(n)))
```

This is the code to calculate the intersection.

to filter them out you will do this

```js
console.log([1,1,2,10,11].filter((n) => ![1,2,3,4,5].includes(n)))
```

To remove an element `x` from an array `arr` we can do this

```js
    var array = [1,2,3];
    var index = array.indexOf(3);
    if( index >= 0)
       array.splice(index,1);
```

Removing an element also answers your question on how to check if the elements exist in the array.

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can create a snippet using that. Also there are many posts on finding intersection between 2 arrays

Comment: Also it does not answers *How do I remove arr1[i] from arr2?*

Answer (score 0):

try with `arr2 .filter(val => !arr1.includes(val));` to remove duplicate value from `second array`

```js
var arr1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3];
var arr2 = [1, 4, 3, 1, 1];
arr2 = arr2 .filter(val => !arr1.includes(val));

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store all unique values along with its frequency in an object using `array#reduce` and then filter result by looking into unique object using `array#filter` and decrementing the frequency once you find the same value. After that simply return length.

```js
const arr1 = [1,1,2,3,3],
      arr2 = [1,4,3,1,1];

var commonCount = (ar1, ar2) => {
  const uniques = ar1.reduce((res, v) => {
    res[v] = (res[v] || 0) + 1;
    return res;
  },{});
  const common = arr2.filter(v => uniques[v] > 0 && uniques[v]--);
  return common.length;
}

console.log(commonCount(arr1,arr2));
```